# Connecting to oracle data visualisation cloud service with node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, node-oracledb, oracle-analytics

I’m looking to integrate reports/charts from oracle data visualisation cloud service to my web application which is using node js for backend and angular for front end. I have a dev server in oracle cloud with the reports and charts ready. How can I get started to use the api from oracle cloud using node js . Is there any modules that support this ? Or can any one guide me on how to establish the connection and authenticate it. Can anyone share related documents as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this video to see how to integrate Oracle Data Visualization Cloud with HTML pages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iprmy_ppp_4

Also, see the following for more info: 
https://medium.com/@insight2action/oracle-analytics-cloud-developer-experience-fe510b5507e9

Comment: You could use any of the methods in [this article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) to connect to the [DVCS API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/data-visualization-cloud/bidap/SendRequests.html).